# 404 Response in /token request

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to receive an access token from the Microsoft Graph API following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#token-request). So I perform a POST request in Node, but I get a 404 error status:

```
const tokenRequestUrl = [
    `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${config.tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1?client_id=${config.appClient.id}`,
    `scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default`,
    `client_secret=${config.appClient.password}`,
    "grant_type=client_credentials"
].join("&");
request.post(
    tokenRequestUrl,
    {
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
    },
    (err, req, body) => {
        console.log(req.statusCode, body); // 404, ""
    }
);
```

Some debugging information (hidden):

- Tenant ID: `XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`
- App Client Id: `XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`
- APP Client Password: `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accidentally have the protocol version in your URL. You have `oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1?client_id` You need to remove `HTTP/1.1` in the URL. so it looks like `oauth2/v2.0/token?client_id`

Comment: Thanks! I sure do hope their example I linked is updated. It looks like it's part of the url.